# Solution Verification - Conditional probability

Tags: solution-verification, conditional-probability

the question tells me that $P(A|B)>P(A)$ and needs me to prove:

1. $P(B|A)>P(B)$
2. $P(B^c|A)<P(B^c)$

In general all I want to ask is do I need to care that $P(B)>0$ or $P(A)>0$ for the conditional probability, and how do I do it if I do need to. 

**Here's how I proved**: 
Knowing that $P(A|B)>P(A)$ I know that $\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}>P(A)\Rightarrow P(A\cap B)>P(A)P(B)$.

1. I can write it as $P(B\cap A) > P(B)P(A)$ (After multiplying $P(A)>0$, I assumed it's $>0$ because otherwise I wouldn't have $P(B|A)?$ - and exactly right here is my question, can I do this? if not, say $P(A)=0$ how do I prove (1)?

I did prove (2) also using (1), but I think that getting an answer about (1) will be enough for me to keep going. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $P(A)=0$ then  the hypothesis becomes $0 >0$ which is false. So we must have $P(A) >0$ and 1) follows from the hyptohesis by your argument.

Comment: Thanks for the help, so It's better to add this as an explanation in the start so I can use $P(A)>0$ etc...?

Comment: Yes, you have to mention that $P(A) >0$ necessarily. @Pwaol

Answer (score 0):

> I think that getting an answer about (1) will be enough for me to keep going.

What you are asking is immediate. In fact,

If

$$\mathbb{P}[A|B]>\mathbb{P}[A]$$

this means that

$$\mathbb{P}[A\cap B]>\mathbb{P}[A]\cdot\mathbb{P}[B]$$

which is exactly the same condition as

$$\mathbb{P}[B|A]>\mathbb{P}[B]$$